# FindNext property of Range Object cannot be assigned

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have written a code, which includes the FindNext method. All the code works so far, only when it gets to the FindNext method it shows an error saying the FindNext Object cannot be assigned.
However, I don't see where the Range Object (in this case "cell") is changed in any way for the FindNext method to not be able to assign it. Has anybody got an idea?

Please ignore any chunky written code, I'm very new with VBA ;)

```
Sub Search()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim cell As Range, sngCell As Range
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim firstCell As String
    
    Dim rg As Range, lastColumn As Long
    
    Set cell = wks.Cells.Find(what:="Planned Supply at BP|SL (EA)", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    firstCell = cell.Address
    
    Do
    
    With wks
        lastColumn = .Cells(cell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rg = Range(cell, .Cells(cell.Row, lastColumn))
    End With
    
    For Each sngCell In rg
    If IsNumeric(sngCell.Value) = True Then
        If sngCell.Value > 0 Then
            If sngCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value > sngCell.Value Then
            Count = Count + 1
            End If
            If Count = 0 Then
            Rows(sngCell.Row - 2).Delete
            Rows(sngCell.Row - 1).Delete
            Rows(sngCell.Row).Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next
    
    Set cell = wks.Cells.FindNext(cell)
    
    Loop While cell.Address <> firstCell

End Sub
```

Comment: `Rows(sngCell.Row).Delete` is deleting the row `cell.row`

Comment: I haven't run the code, but the loop over `rg` deletes rows, and it is possible you delete the row to which `cell` refers, which would cause problems.

Comment: Don't you need to reset `Count` at some point?

Answer (score 1):

`Find()` in a loop is complex enough that it's worth splitting it out into a separate function.  Here's a slightly different approach which reduces the complexity in your main Sub and allows you to focus on the business rules instead of the nuances of using `Find()`

```vb
Sub Search()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, sngCell As Range
    Dim firstCell As String
    Dim rg As Range, lastColumn As Long, matches As Collection
    
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    
    Set matches = FindAll(wks.Cells, "Planned Supply at BP|SL (EA)")
    
    For Each cell In matches
        Debug.Print "Found:", cell.Address
        Set rg = wks.Range(cell, wks.Cells(cell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        For Each sngCell In rg.Cells
            If IsNumeric(sngCell.Value) Then  'no need for `= True`
                If sngCell.Value > 0 Then
                    If sngCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value <= sngCell.Value Then
                        sngCell.Offset(-2, 0).Resize(3).EntireRow.Delete
                        Exit For 'stop checking...
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next cell
End Sub

'Find all matches for `val` in `rng` and return as a collection
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range, addr As String
    
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.CountLarge), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```